# How to join on different columns when the one you want to join on is null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join 2 tables on 4 different columns. However, one of these columns is sometimes blank and is causing an unexpected output in the final table.

I have the following dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE #df 
(
    CityID bigint,
    StateID VARCHAR (5),
    HospitalID bigint,
    ProviderID BIGINT,
    PT_Count BIGINT 
);

INSERT INTO #df (CityID, StateID, HospitalID, ProviderID, PT_Count)
VALUES
(70289, 'WY', 10001, 34523, 300),
(70500, 'AZ', 15000, NULL ,200),
(34523, 'NM', 54634, 78543, 100),
(90010, 'CA', 65738, NULL, 500)
```

and would like to join it to this dataset

```
CREATE TABLE #df2 
(
    CityID bigint,
    City_Name VARCHAR(20),
    StateID VARCHAR (5),
    State_Name VARCHAR(20),
    HospitalID bigint,
    Hospital_Name VARCHAR(20),
    ProviderID BIGINT,
    Provider_Name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO #df2 (CityID, City_Name, StateID, State_Name, HospitalID, Hospital_Name, ProviderID, Provider_Name)
VALUES
(70289, 'Cheyenne', 'WY', 'Wyoming', '10001', 'Wyoming Gen', 34523, 'Dr.Joe'),
(70500, 'Phoenix', 'AZ', 'Arizona', 15000, 'Arizona Gen', NULL, NULL),
(34523, 'Santa Fe', 'NM', 'New Mexico', '54634', 'NM Gen',78543, 'Dr. Jim'),
(90010, 'Beverly Hills', 'CA', 'California', 65738, 'Bev Gen', NULL, NULL)
```

When I run the following query, the records with null provider ids have null record for CityName, StateName, and HospitalName. This should not be the case.

How can I fix this?

```
SELECT a.CityID
     , b.City_Name
     , a.StateID
     , b.State_Name
     , a.HospitalID
     , b.Hospital_Name
     , a.ProviderID
     , b.Provider_Name
     , a.PT_Count
FROM #df a
LEFT JOIN #df2 b ON b.CityID = a.CityID 
                 AND b.HospitalID = a.HospitalID 
                 AND b.ProviderID = a.ProviderID 
                 AND b.StateID = a.StateID
```

Comment: In your example, since there is one `city`/`hospital`/`state` match in each table and you don't want `null` providers to prevent a match, why are you joining on `provider` at all? If you need to join on `provider` in some cases, you might need to add that case to your sample data.

Comment: Update your post with your current output and the expected output.

Comment: You can use a sentinel value instead of null, if i want to do these kind of joins. If you for example knows that -1 is not a valid provider, you can do: ISNULL(a.providerID, -1) = ISNULL(b.providerID, -1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare nulls with `=`. If you want to join rows where both can have nulls in `ProviderID` you can use something like this:

```sql
SELECT a.CityID
     , b.City_Name
     , a.StateID
     , b.State_Name
     , a.HospitalID
     , b.Hospital_Name
     , a.ProviderID
     , b.Provider_Name
     , a.PT_Count
FROM #df a
LEFT JOIN #df2 b ON b.CityID = a.CityID 
                 AND b.HospitalID = a.HospitalID 
                 AND (b.ProviderID = a.ProviderID 
                      or (b.ProviderID  is null and a.ProviderID is null))
                 AND b.StateID = a.StateID
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TeNUtwid).